# How to explode a list of string into new columns

Tags: postgresql-14

I have a table in postgresql 14 like this one:

```
text                classes
some string         [food, drink]
another string      [food, medicine, drink]
another random      [car]
```

**And I want to get this as output:**

```
text                class_1   class_2  class_3
some string         food       drink      
another string      food     medicine   drink
another random      car
```

So I want to strip the `[]` off and explode each of the string into columns.

I am trying:

```
select text, replace(replace(unnest(string_to_array(classes, ',')), '[', ' '),']','') from tbl
```

but i am getting each of the classes in one line which duplicates the text columns

Also, is there any clean way to remove the `[]`?

Comment: Sigh. Why do people "invent" so many new formats of storing lists when there are perfectly fine supported solutions like JSON, or proper arrays. But storing multiple values in  a single column is usually a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translate` to get rid of the square brackets. Then use `split_part` to get one column for each element:

```
select "text", 
       split_part(translate(classes, '[]', ''), ',', 1) as class_1,
       split_part(translate(classes, '[]', ''), ',', 2) as class_2,
       split_part(translate(classes, '[]', ''), ',', 3) as class_3
from the_table;
```

It is **not** possible to make this dynamic. A fundamental restriction of the the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all result columns must be known before the database starts retrieving data.